# How can I pass a variable in eq JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <html>
     <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div id=parent_div0>
              <div>
                 <button class=cd type="button" id="add_step" > Add step0! </button>
              </div>
              <div><button  class=cd type="button" id="add_faizlami" > Add stepss0!</button></div>
              <input type='submit' name='submit'>
           </div>
           <div id=parent_div1>
              <div><button type="button" id="add_step1" > Add step1! </button></div>
              <div><button  type="button" id="add_faizlami" > Add stepss1!</button></div>
           </div>
           <div id=parent_div2>
              <div><button  type="button" id="add_step2" > Add step2!</button></div>
              <div><button   type="button" id="add_faizlami2" > Add stepss2!</button></div>
           </div>    
           <br/>
        </form> 
          <script>
             var l='hello';
             var counter=0;
             var variable='parent_div' +counter;
             $('#' + variable div:eq(' + counter + ')).append(l);
          </script>  
     </body>
  </html>
```

I have parent_div1, parent_div2 etc.(it will be dynamic and so I don't know the last one) in html and in each parent _div, I have several divs and i would like to append 'Hello' to the last div of a parent_div based on the value of the variable counter, but my appending line isn't working. Is there any problem with the syntax? I would really appreciate any help. I have been trying long to make this work.

Comment: I have the click functionality added too but  this is the line not working $('#' + variable div:eq(' + counter + ')).append(l);

Comment: $('#' + variable + ' div:eq(' + counter + ')')

Comment: The syntax problem aside, you seem to be applying `counter` twice: once in building the value for `variable` and the second time in the value for `div:eq()`. This is overkill, once should be enough to clearly address your target div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$(`#${variable} div:eq(${counter})`)
```